# criar efeito hide e show de link de noticias com classes e ajax

Tags: php, javascript

tenho a a classe que recupera dados do banco

```
public function ListAjNot(){
    try{
        $lernot = "SELECT tit_postjauport, pos_postjauport FROM noticia ";
        $listnot = $this->con->Connect()->prepare($lernot);
        $listnot->execute();
        $retListSelecionada = $listnot->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($retListSelecionada);
        }
     catch(PDOException $erro5){
     echo 'erro'.$erro5->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Essa classe é utilizada pelo javascript($ajax) para recuperar dados na minha div `:col-md-12` como mostro abaixo.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#col-md-12').empty();                 
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',                        //Defino o método HTTP usado
        dataType: 'json',                   //Defino tipo de retorno
        url: 'noticias.class.php',          //Defino o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
     });
});
```

queria criar uma link de noticias do banco de dados, onde o usuário vai clicar no titulo e abaixo do titulo ele vai abrir o a noticia respectiva ao link..mas isso de forma dinâmica... veja abaixo a tela de onde estão os links ele me traz as informações porem desconfiguradas. porque não consigo colocar o efeito hide e show nesses links e abrir individualmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Primeiramente, você terá que fazer a consulta por **ajax**, passando a `id` da notícia para o seu `noticias.class.php` saber qual notícia ele vai retornar.

**2)** Passar uma `id` para o `noticias.class.php` não é tão simples, mas pode ser feito por **ajax**. Vamos ao código.

**3)** Crie um `input` escondido com o `id` da notícia que deseja carregar. Com isso você poderá transferir o valor para o **javascript**.

```
<input type="hidden" value="999" id="someid" />
```

**4)** Agora vamos ao código do **javascript** com **jquery**.

```
    var loadid = $('#someid').val();
    $("#col-md-12" ).load( "noticias.class.php",{loadid:loadid});
    $(".clicarnoticia").on( "click", ".clicarnoticia", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".loading-div").show();
        var page = $(this).attr("data-page");
            $('#col-md-12').empty();
            $("#col-md-12").load("noticias.class.php",{page:page,loadid:loadid}, function(){
                $(".loading-div").hide();
            });
    });
```

**5)** Agora crie uma `div` com a classe `.loading-div`. Quando ele clicar, essa `div` será exibida como um **carregando...** e depois vai desaparecer.

**6)** No seu arquivo `noticias.class.php`, você deve receber a `ID` da notícia para adicionar no `WHERE` da sua consulta **SQL**. Claro, com os devidos cuidados com **SQL Injection**, verificando se é feito apenas com números.

```
if(isset($_POST["loadid"])){
$loadid = filter_var($_POST["loadid"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
}
if (is_numeric($loadid)) {} else {echo '<br><center>O que você está tentando? Seu IP já foi registrado.</center>';die();}
   echo $loadid;
```

**Observações:** cada notícia deve ter um `id` em um `input`, para poder passar esse valor por meio de **ajax**. Veja bem, `.clicarnoticia` é a classe do hiperlink. Agora basta você adaptar ai no seu projeto.

**Dica extra:** você pode adicionar os efeitos de **fade** do **jquery**, fica bem bonito.