# Criar um botão que abra uma aba/popup/etc de formulário de orçamento no Magento

Tags: magento, popup

nos precisamos de fazer um código no CMS **Magento.**

Seguinte, vamos fazer um botão abrir uma janela de orçamento (pode ser um popup, porem só abrindo ao clicar no botão), *com Nome do Produto, Nome da pessoa, E-mail, Código do Produto, cel e etc.* No fim, sera mandado para um email admin, deste formulário, para que então possamos contatar, de volta, o "cliente".

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Para a parte de abrir a janela:

Utilize **jQuery Dialog** para abrir uma janela legal tipo modal.

```
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form
```

Ou então, utilize o **Vex**, que é uma dialog muito bonita também.

```
http://github.hubspot.com/vex/docs/welcome/
```

O formulário você pode carregar por **ajax**. Veja nesta pergunta:

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216454/criar-efeito-hide-e-show-de-link-de-noticias-com-classes-e-ajax/216469#216469
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações. Sera que teria algum vídeo ensinando a programar em magento? Não entendo NADA de magento. So o básico (mexer no back e front).

Muito obrigado, novamente.

Comment: Aqui tem vários: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=curso+magento
 Também, você encontra cursos de Magento em português lá na plataforma Udemy.